# How to call method from another fragment

Tags: java, android

Good day everyone. I have checkedListener in fragment and i need to type in this listener some method, but data which need to use i have in another fragment. How to send this data from different fragments? Can i call checkedListener from another fragment and type some rule for him in mainActivity class ? I will be very grateful for help. Thank you.

How example i send sreeshot that i need to create (first square on the top this is mainFragment which have data of the Sum -1+4 and in bottom with diamonts i have another fragment which have checkedListener and i need to compare sum from different fragments and if true i need to setTextColor in text): 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Juan answer suggests fragments should not communicate directly. this is how you manage to do so.

this is your activity class that implements the interface defined in fragment

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentInterface {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public void fragmentInterfaceMethod(int your_value) {
        //use your_value to send it to another fragment
    }

}
```

your fragment class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   public interface FragmentInterface {
       void fragmentInterfaceMethod(int your_value);
   }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_word_definition, container, false);

        int myValue = 123;
        ((FragmentInterface)getActivity()).fragmentInterfaceMethod(myValue);

        return mView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are not intended to talk directly between each other.
You can do one of two things:

1 - Store the data in an activity common to the two fragments and have each fragment get and set the data throught the activity.

or

2 - If the data is really bound to one of the fragments, then have the other fragment ask the activity to provide the data. And in turn the activity can ask the framgment that has the data to hand it over so it can pass it to the requesting frament.

The communication between fragment and activity can be done with an interface or by directly casting the activity to its concrete class.

And in the other direction by using a reference to the corresponding fragment.

Note: if you use a ViewPager for your fragments, getting the current fragment instance needs some extra steps.